# Назначение функций empty и isset

Tags: php

Что означает `empty`? Что означает `isset`? Что означает `!empty` и что означает `!isset`?
С помощью Google ничего толкового не нашел.

P.S. А по поводу восклицательных знаков ничего не нашел.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`isset` - существует ли переменная.

`empty` - пуста ли переменная.

Ну а со знаком "!" все наоборот :)

Comment: И добавлю для любителей экономить на спичках: isset работает быстрее.

Answer (score 1):

`Empty()` определяет установленна ли переменная: [описание](http://php.su/functions/?empty).

`Isset()` тоже определяет, установленная ли переменная: [описание](http://php.su/functions/?isset).

У них есть отличия, читай по ссылкам.

"!" значит отрицание, например:

```
<?php
$a = null;
if (!isset($a)) Echo "Переменная не установленна";
?>
```